# Home loads under navabr

Tags: css, reactjs

```
import Home from './components/Home/Home.jsx'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom"
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

`App.css`:

```
.container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Navbar CSS

```
import React from "react";
import cart from "../assets/images/cart.png"
import { TfiMenu } from "react-icons/tfi";
import { AiOutlineCloseCircle} from "react-icons/ai";
export default function Navbar() {
  const [open, setopen] = React.useState(false);
  let Links = [
    {name:"Home" ,link:"/"},
    {name:"Headphone" ,link:"/"},
    {name:"Speaker" ,link:"earphones"},
    {name:"Earphone"  ,link:"/"},
  ];
  const change= ()=> {
    setopen(!open);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className=" fixed shadow-md w-full  top-0 left-0 ">
        <div className="  lg:flex items-center bg-black py-4 md:justify-around">
          <div className=" flex justify-between px-3 pt-2  text-white cursor-pointer font-[Poppins]">
            audiophile
            <div onClick={change} className=" lg:hidden  w-9 inline-block">
              {
                open 
                  ? (<span className=""><AiOutlineCloseCircle/></span>) 
                  : (<span  className=""><TfiMenu/></span>)
              }
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul className={`lg:flex md:items-center ${open ?"" :"hidden"} `}>
            { Links.map((link) => (
              <li className='  md:ml-8 text-xl md:my-0 my-7'> 
                <a href={link.link} className='text-white hover:text-yellow-500 duration-500'>{link.name}</a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          <div className>
            <img className="absolute right-20   md:inline-block  w-7 cursor- top-5 " src={cart} alt="cart" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

this is my code and whenever I try to load the home top portion is always under the navbar. .my navbar is positioned sticky. also can't make my home width to 100. maybe because it is under another component. to render it properly i am using margin-top (mt-44) or else its under navabr  Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: oh please indent your code properly.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ sorry i forgot to indent it while pasting

Comment: @ATHULSURESH mark it as a css question please.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-platform-7zhjlt?file=/src/Navbar.js Please replicate your code here

Comment: @DreamBold hey sorry for the late reply.i added my code in that link

Comment: Please send me the link to your sandbox

Comment: @DreamBold https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-carson-o5dvod?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

you should move your container one level up and move your navbar out of it like this:

```
import Home from './components/Home/Home.jsx'
import Earphones from './components/Earphones/Earphones'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
import {BrowserRouter,Routes,Route} from "react-router-dom"
export default function App()
{
return(
<div className="container">
 <Navbar/>
 <BrowserRouter>
 <div className="anothercontainer"> 
         <Routes>
           <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
         </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
</div>
</div>
)
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply tried that too but it is still the same. I am using tailwind CSS for all others components.I hope it is not closing with plain CSS in App.js

Comment: edit your post and provide complete css code.

Comment: css for navbar?

Comment: css for navbar and container.

Comment: Already pasted container code